# Pytest: Do we have any hooks to check whether the fixture is been executed positively?

Tags: python, pytest, hook, fixtures

I wanted my tests to be skipped if there is any issue with module setup data/fixtures, do we have any hooks that gives information regarding this ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'correctly'? If an error happend during fixture's run, you get an exception. Fixtures should always run successful.

Comment: @MaratMkhitaryan I mean to say i am working on something where the tests needs to be skipped when the module set up data is been failed. Ideally tests needs to be skipped when there is any issue with fixtures. Now all the tests gets failed rather i would want it to be skipped with appropriate message saying the tests are been skipped because of failure in module setup data

Comment: Have you tried using https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#skipping-test-functions? If the test fails because of an exception you can use try except with pytest.skip.